# Eclipse disappears after being minimized in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 yesterday via the Wubi installer and the only problem I am having is that if I minimize Eclipse, I can't find it again. If I try to open Eclipse I get a message telling me that my workspace is already in use (this means the other window is still running).

What can I do about this?

Comment: And I have the same problem on Windows XP

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch between windows using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If that doesn't work you can try to find the Java process and see if it's running by launching a console and typing:

```
ps ax | grep 'eclipse'
```

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with `Sublime Text 2`, not with `eclipse`. I can see it running with a `ps` command. This has happened multiple times, normally after leaving my system running overnight and re-entering my password from the screensaver. It doesn't happen every time, however.

Comment: Also, when close everything and restart the computer, for a second or two during shutdown, my running `Sublime Text 2` app shows up on my screen, then the system reboots. @brewer2 - does this happen to you too?